# How to download file from URL all * files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-scraping, download

I would like to download all *.dmg files from a particular URL using java code. E.g.
http://testURL.com/fileRepository/ 
host all *.dmg and i would like all *.dmg files with original file names using Java program and store them with original file name to local drive.

I am able to download individual files if i know the file name but the problem is i don't know all file names, i only know these files are dmg files.

Please answer. Below is my sample program

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    String fileName = "myPackage.dmg"; //The file that will be saved on your computer
    URL link = new URL("http://mytestURL/fileRepository/"+fileName);

 //Code to download
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int n = 0;
     while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
     {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
     }
     out.close();
     in.close();
     byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
     fos.write(response);
     fos.close();
 //End download code

     System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

Comment: Jave has a regex library that can help you get all files with .dmg format...

Comment: Thanks ryekayo, can you please provide an example for above case?

Comment: Give me a few and I will do so.

Comment: Thanks ryekayo. That would be helpful

Comment: got an answer, it may need some fiddling but the regex you need is there.

Comment: There's no generic way to list the files under a particular URL path unless the web server chooses to share that information (e.g. if accessing the directory URL gives you an HTML page with a directory listing).

Comment: Yes Ian, that's what i understood so far. What if i do html scrapping and it list all href? But problem with this approach is, it is asking for user name/password. I am using jsoup to get html details and then build the path dynamically with full file name.